# I can ping the PC from remote server but can't connect to a port

Tags: firewall, router, connection, telnet

I did my research but I still can't figure out the solution.
I want to connect to port 8888 of my PC from a remote server.
When I ping my PC from a remote server with `ping <my ip>`, it pings.
When I try to connect to 8888 port using `telnet <my ip> 8888`, it prints `Connection refused`.
https://canyouseeme.org/ shows "Connection refused" when I try to connect to my ip, port 8888.
I have a static IP option by ISP.
ISP doesn't block the port (at least the support says so).
8888 is listened (`sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 8888`).
Wi-Fi Router Firewall is turned off.
DMZ on Wi-Fi Router is turned on.
Ubuntu Firewall is turned off (`sudo ufw status` prints "Inactive").
I can connect from my PC to itself using `telnet 127.0.0.1 8888`.

What else am I missing? The next step I'm going to take is to avoid Wi-Fi Router and to connect the PC directly (I need a converter for it, I will get it tomorrow).

Comment: Sounds like the service configured to only listen on localhost rather than external interfaces / IP’s

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Comment: @HBruijn no, it didn't help

Comment: @HBruijn thank you a lot! It is true. I googled and someone suggested to use 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost in the code. I did it and now I can telnet into my PC and it's seen on canyouseeme.org

Comment: It's the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33953447/express-app-server-listen-all-interfaces-instead-of-localhost-only

Comment: @daubs-05colobus Your current setup is insecure and will be exploited in its current setup, if it hasn't already been _(it's a matter of when, not if)_. **WAN facing router firewalls should _never_ be disabled** - there is literally no use case for this.  **A PC should _never_ be placed within a DMZ** - there is literally no use case for this; instead, forward the correct ports [DNAT], as the only OSes intended to be exposed to WAN are router OSes. **Telnet should _never_ be used**, as it lacks encryption and is not secure _(there is no secure implementation of `telnet`)_ - instead, use SSH.

Comment: @JW0914 Thank you. I turned off DMZ and used port forwarding for 8888 instead. I don't use telnet, it's only for port checking. I don't use SSH neither - my app uses TCP/UDP as far as I understand (it's asyncio library for Python, I don't know what's under the hood). I have some problem turning on router firewall back. Is it a big deal?

Comment: @daubs-05colobus The router firewall being off is a HUGE deal - all devices and data downstream of it are now exposed directly to WAN with no firewall. Power off your modem until the router firewall is enabled and working - if you're unable to enable the WAN firewall on the router, factory reset the router. I would also clean install OSes on all downstream devices and run extensive malware scans on all data, as the router firewall blocks tens of thousands of WAN-side  inbound requests _daily_; if your WAN IP happened to belong to a business in the past, that can jump into the 100Ks

Comment: @daubs-05colobus If it was my setup, I would treat every device on your LAN as having been compromised, and I would recommend not introducing any new devices onto your LAN or enabling internet access to any device on your LAN until OSes have been clean installed and all files extensively scanned for malware - I would never treat any device, file, or piece of data as secure on that network otherwise. What's been done is literally the worst possible thing that could be done.

Comment: @JW0914 I factory reset the router